# Как ускорить процесс скрапинга в Селениуме?

Tags: python, многопоточность, selenium, multiprocessing

Нужно собрать оклоло 200,000 позиций с сайта. На одну позицию , уходит примерно 25 секунд. Нужно ускорить процесс если это возможно. А то я поседею пока извлеку всю информацию). Спасибо

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options



links_list = []
for x in range(4, 10):
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True


    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='./geckodriver')
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.get(f'https://www.imobiliare.ro/vanzare-apartamente/bucuresti?pagina={x}')
    time.sleep(4)

    cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a').click()

    ap_link = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('img-block')
    for item in ap_link:
        all_links = item.get_property('href')
        links_list.append(all_links)




    try:
        ivory = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/button').click()
    except:
        pass
ap_list = []
try:
    ivory = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/button').click()
except:
    pass
for index, item in enumerate(links_list):
    try:
        ivory = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/button').click()
    except:
        pass
    driver.get(item)
    time.sleep(1)
    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/h1').text
    try:
        phone_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/a').click()
    except:
        phone_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span/a').click()

    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        ivory_phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span').text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        ivory_phone = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nrtel').text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        ivory_phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span').text
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        whois = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]').text
    except:
        whois = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]').text
    try:
        ivory = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/button').click()
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(1)

    time.sleep(1)
    location = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]').text.replace(' - Vezi hartă', '')
    time.sleep(1)
    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]').text
    try:
        more = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/p/span[1]/a').click()
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        details = driver.find_element_by_id('b_detalii_text').text.replace('Detalii', '')
    except:
        details = 'NA'
    time.sleep(1)
    caracteristici = driver.find_element_by_id('b_detalii_caracteristici').text.replace('Caracteristici', '')
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
      specificatii = driver.find_element_by_id('b_detalii_specificatii').text.replace('Specificaţii', '')
    except:
        specificatii = 'NA'

apartamente = {
    'Titlu': name,
    'Locatie': location,
    'Vanzator': whois,
    'Telefon': ivory_phone,
    'Pret': price,
    'Detalii': details,
    'Caracteristici': caracteristici,
    'Specificatii': specificatii
}

ap_list.append(apartamente)

# with Pool(10) as p:
#     p.map(ap_list)
print(str(index + 1) + '  Salvat: ', apartamente['Titlu'])

df = pd.DataFrame(ap_list)
df.to_excel('Apartamente_Bucuresti.xlsx', encoding='UTF-8', engine='xlsxwriter')

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: самое быстрое будет не использовать селениум, либо использовать вебдрайвервайт вместо time.sleep, или использовать контейнеры

Comment: Без селениума не могу. по другому не получается вытащить номер телефона .

Comment: Я бы начал с того, что переписал все локаторы на css..